# Почему не нажимаются радио-кнопки?

Tags: html, css, css3

есть несколько радио-кнопок, сделал кастомные стили, но они не нажимаются. Без стилей кнопки работают но не отрабатывает нажатие по  label, в чем может быть причина?

```css
.answers-block div {
   margin: 10px 0;
}


.radio {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
 margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
 .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .radio + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
 }
.radio + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
.radio:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}
```

```html
  <form action="javascript:" id="questionnaire-form" method="post" novalidate>
<section class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs-container">

    <div class="tab">
      <div class="question_text"> Первый вопрос</div>
      <div class="answers-block">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="answer_1" value="Ответ_1" class="radio">
          <label for="answer_1">Ответ_1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="answer_1" value="Ответ_2" class="radio">
          <label for="answer_1">Ответ_2</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="answer-text" name="answer_1_text" placeholder="Свой вариант...">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-tabs">
        <a href="javascript:" class="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="javascript:" class="next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Расположите input внутри label:

```
<label ...>
    <input ...>
    Ответ ...
</label>
```

Заодно избавитесь от необходимости прописывать id для каждой пары input - label.

Answer (score 4):

id добавьте у input-ов в соответствии с for у каждого label

```css
.answers-block div {
   margin: 10px 0;
}
.radio {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: -1;
 opacity: 0;
 margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
 .radio + label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
 .radio + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #FFF;
 }
.radio + label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #9FD468;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}
.radio:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:" id="questionnaire-form" method="post" novalidate>
<section class="tabs">
  <div class="tabs-container">

    <div class="tab">
      <div class="question_text"> Первый вопрос</div>
      <div class="answers-block">
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="answer_1" value="Ответ_1" class="radio" id="answer_1">
          <label for="answer_1">Ответ_1</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="radio" name="answer_1" value="Ответ_2" class="radio" id="answer_2">
          <label for="answer_2">Ответ_2</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" class="answer-text" name="answer_1_text" placeholder="Свой вариант...">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-tabs">
        <a href="javascript:" class="prev">prev</a>
        <a href="javascript:" class="next">next</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```